# MongoDB Date range query for past hour

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write MongoDB query which will be return data from one hour ago.
There is a column `time` with timestamps (`"time" : NumberLong("1471953787012")`) and this is how it looks in SQL:

```
select name from table
where time between (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND (NOW())
```

How do I write a MongoDB query to find a date range from one hour ago?
I'm trying with `new Date()` function but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
db.coll.find({ 
  "time" : { 
    $lt: new Date(), 
    $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
  }   
})
```

Comment: @ReyanChougle Unfortunately, I cannot get any result with solution that you provide :(

Comment: I'm trying `db.coll.find({$and:[{time:{$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)}},{time: {$lte: ISODate()}}]})`

Comment: Also, I was trying with index on another field and a date range like: `db.coll.find({ Name: "Name1", time: {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60), $lt: ISODate().getTime()}});`

Comment: Did you found the solution? As I have checked my post its working fine

Comment: I have tried to execute query, but I cannot get result from the mongo shell. Could be the problem in date format? It's a NumberLong `("time" : NumberLong("1471953787012"))`

Comment: @corry Hi, how did you solve this? Having the same issue for me as well.

Comment: @kiranbkrishna bellow is the answer, and for my problem the solution is:  `db.collection('col').aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              Time: {
                 $gte: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60
              }
            },
            {
              Time: {
                $lte: new Date().getTime()
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
db.entity.find({ $and:[
    {
    "timestamp": {
        $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)
    }}, 
    { 
    "timestamp": {
        $lte: ISODate()
    }}
]})
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: There is no need of `$and` and `$lte`. Anything greater than 1 hour ago from now will hold true what OP is asking.

Comment: @Saleem.. You are right but what if anyone wants to search for second timestamp which is not same as current datetime

Answer (score 8):

```
db.coll.find({
    "time": { // 60 minutes ago (from now)
        $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)
    }
})
```